# Is it possible to overlay a list of zip codes on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to do a small Google Maps mashup.  I have a list of mostly adjacent zip codes.  I would like to bring up a webpage with Google Maps embedded into it and overlay the zip codes with, say, transparent green tile.

Is it possible with Google Maps? 
If so, can someone point me to an example.

I've done some Fiddlering on a couple of sites that do something similar and they seemed to be bringing back a collection of polylines from them own sites.  Can what I want be done exclusively with Google Maps?

Answer (score 3):

This should not be a problem, 
here is a site a made a few years ago that displays all the zip codes using google maps.

http://reichalex.de/zip/

here is the google api docu on Polylines

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Polylines_Overview

http://searchengineland.com/google-adds-zip-code-outlines-to-map-one-box-77733